# I want to read those inputs in a single line separated by space in java without using String?

Tags: java, arrays

```
    System.out.println("Number of pages + Number of lost pages + Number of Readers");
    
    int n = s.nextInt();
    int m = s.nextInt();
    int q = s.nextInt();
```

I want to read input values all the values are going to be integer but I want to read it in a same line with changing it form Integer.

Comment: one line? without a String? and how do you suppose to tell your application to read, if not for pressing enter?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `s` is an instance of `Scanner`: Your code, as written, does exactly what you want.

scanners are created by default with a delimiter configured to be 'any whitespace'. `nextInt()` reads the next token (which are the things in between the delimiter, i.e. the whitespace), and returns it to you by parsing it into an integer.

Thus, **your code as pasted works fine**.

If it doesn't, stop setting up a delimiter, or reset it back to 'any whitespace' with e.g. `scanner.reset();` or `scanner.useDelimiter("\\s+");`.

```
class Example {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    var in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter something:");
    System.out.println(in.nextInt());
    System.out.println(in.nextInt());
    System.out.println(in.nextInt());
  }
}
```

works fine here.